# Using Variable in $(data-option-value)

Tags: jquery, selector

I have this jQuery code

```
var  c = ".c10";
$('[data-option-value="c"]a').trigger("click")
```

This code performs the click event. `c10` is an id from one specific element. This code works fine without using variable : `$('[data-option-value=".c10"]a').trigger("click")`

As you see in the first code I used variable instead of using it directly but I didn't get any answer. Did I miss something?

Hope someone could help!

Comment: You need to concatenate the variable to the string. See the duplicates I marked for more information

Comment: Try this: $('[data-option-value='+c+']a').trigger("click");

Comment: thanks @RoryMcCrossan